# How to retrieve current city name using wifi/3g ip address with iPhone/iOS programming (Objective-c)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, location

I want to retrieve the current "city name" of the iPhone using ip address of device (wifi/3g). Is there any way to do it? please help me out.

Following is the place where I want the current location.

```
-(BOOL)fetchAndParseRss{

NSString * CurrentLocation = <I want the retrieved Location here!!>;
NSString * URLrss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://news.google.com/news?q=location:%@&output=rss", CurrentLocation];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLrss]; 
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
}
```

Actually i am developing an app for myself that displays the news of current city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CLLocationManager` and `MKReverseGeocoder` to get users city.

First add `CLLocationManager` and start updating user location

```
- (void)startLocationManager 
{    
    if (locManager==nil)
        locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if (locManager.locationServicesEnabled)
    {
        NSLog(@"User has opted out of service on it error");
    } else {
        locManager.delegate = self;
        locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
        [locManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Then add location manager delegate methods to use `MKReverseGeocoder`.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Manager error: %@", [error description]);
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    self.geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    [geocoder release];
    geocoder.delegate = self;
    [geocoder start];
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and of course you have to implement `MKReverseGeocoder` Delegate methods

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:%@ didFailWithError:%@", geocoder, error);
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{   
    // with the placemark you can now retrieve the city name
    NSString *city = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"];
    NSLog(@"City is %@", city);
}
```

This method can be use if user gives permission to your application for location manager.

Comment: `if ([geocoder retainCount])` is complete nonsense.  The memory management in this code is generally wrong. Releasing a parameter without a retain indicates bugs.

Comment: @bbum you are write. it was just a experimental. But releasing a parameter is not completely wrong if you know how to handle your objects. These are delegate methods of your own object.

Comment: @bbum I will ask a question for this, i hope you answer that.

Comment: Releasing a parameter is in direct violation of the memory management patterns of the system.  You are correct that you can do it in a non-crashy fashion in highly controlled cases, but the result will be code that is non-standard and fragile in the face of refactoring over time.

Comment: Also `if ([geocoder retainCount])` is nonsense very much because the *retain count can never be zero*.  It is *impossible* for the `retaincount` to return zero because, by definition, the object has already been destroyed.

Comment: ok i see your point. `if ([geocoder retainCount])` was just an experimental. I have forgotten to delete it. And i also get that releasing a parameter in my situation wont be buggy but it is the violation of pattern. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make an HTTP request to a website like [geoiptool.com](http://www.geoiptool.com/) and scrape the city information from the response. I'm unsure how much success you'll have when using mobile phone networks, though—wifi worked when I tried it on my phone, but 3G didn't.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am totally new to Objective-c. So if you don't mind, Can you share your code with me? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any code on hand to send you. You'll probably want to use `NSXMLParser` (and its `initWithContentsOfURL:` method) to retrieve and parse the website's response. You can find a tutorial on this topic here: http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html